# Cocoa Application setuid

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, setuid

I launch my application with an apple droplet asking for privileges to make the application work as root. Also I need it to read/write settings, so I use *NSUserDefaults*. I call *setuid* (because *NSUserDefaults initWithUser* doesn't work) to set the current user and then read and write his settings.

The problem is that I need to set privileges back to the root for some operations.

```
setuid(0);
```

fails. Any suggestions?

Update:
This is MacOs app, not IOS. OS: 10.8

```
// to set the current user when the app is run with root privileges
CFStringRef temp = SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(NULL, NULL, NULL);
NSString* usrname = (NSString*)temp;
passwd* passwdStruct = getpwnam([usrname UTF8String]);
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
setuid(passwdStruct->pw_uid);
```

Comment: More information/code would be helpful. And if you run a normal Cocoa application, setuid() or getting privileges that way won't work.

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?

Comment: @trojanfoe I run it on  VMWare

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?

Comment: @trojanfoe no it isn't

Comment: @trojanfoe Is it allowed to access "setuid()" if application is sandboxed?